# How to prompt window position in javascript for use in window.open or window.moveto?

Tags: javascript, function, window

For a programming assignment I want to prompt the user for two parameters, positionX and positionY, so that a new window pops up with the (x,y) position whenever opening a new window. So far i tried several options but i can't figure out what I am doing wrong. It may be my syntax as I am pretty new to JavaScript.

My teacher told me the position wasn't correct.

My code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type ="text/javascript">
            function openVenster(){

                //vraag de breedte van het venster op
                var breedte = prompt("Geef de horizontale lengte van het nieuwe venster op (minimaal 100 pixels): ", 100);
                //vraag de hoogte van het venster op
                var hoogte = prompt("Geef de verticale lengte van het nieuwe venster op: (minimaal 100 pixels): ", 100);
                //vraag de x,y posities op waarop het venster moet verschijnen
                var positieX = prompt("Geef de positie ten opzichte van links op in pixels: ", 10);
                var positieY = prompt("Geef de positie ten opzichte van de bovenkant op in pixels: ", 10);

                //open het venster en gebruik ingevoerde posities
                mijnVenster = window.open("http://google.nl","mijnVenster","width=breedte,height=hoogte,scrollbars=no,status=no");
                mijnVenster.moveTo(positieX,positieY);
            }

            function sluitVenster(){

                //sluit het venster
                mijnVenster.close();
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Een JavaScript om een venster te openen en te sluiten</h3>
        <!--
        //weergeef de knoppen
        -->
        <button onclick="openVenster()">Nieuw venster</button>
        <button onclick="sluitVenster()">Sluit venster</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've set up a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uvt8w0xt/1/) with your code. It works properly.

Comment: should be `"width="+breedte+",height="+hoogte` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a mistake but maybe your teacher wants:

```
mijnVenster.moveTo(positieX + 10, positieY + 10);
```

**EDIT** According to your additional question: yes, it can be done inside opening:

```
mijnVenster = window.open("http://google.nl","mijnVenster","left="+positieX+",top="+positieY+",width="+breedte+",height="+hoogte+",scrollbars=no,status=no");
```

Note when passing a variable into a string you have to do it like so:

```
var myVar = 30, str = "A string will get here: my variable";
var newStr = "A string will get here:" + myVar + " my variable";
```

Updated [FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/uvt8w0xt/4/). `mijnVenster.moveTo()` is removed.

Comment: No the assignment is just to use the window.open method/window.moveTo method to open a new Window. The user needs to  fill in the size (width, height) and the position (left, top) at creation.

Comment: My button does not react anymore, it appears the script is interrupted. But i see where you're heading. Let me try to escape my variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the window to finish loading before you can move it.

```
mijnVenster = window.open("http://google.nl","mijnVenster","width=" + breedte + ",height=" + hoogte + ",scrollbars=no,status=no");
            mijnVenster.onload = function(){mijnVenster.moveTo(positieX,positieY);};
```

Comment: I tried it but it still does not work correctly when I test it. For example if I give positionX = 0, positionY = 0 => window appears top left corner. Once again i make a window with positionX = 50, positionY = 50 => window appears top left corner.

Comment: When i was testing your code, the width and height of the new window was larger than my monitor resolution. As you can see in my answer, i hard coded the width and height to 5 and it positioned correctly for me.

Comment: I see but there were no problems with the size of the created window, just the position it pops up.

Comment: Ok, so this issue is that you needed to escape your variables. see update